# Add a div to create padding

Tags: css

I have a span.  Inside it I have two divs.  One used as padding and a second with content.  If the content is multi-line it wraps around my padding div, which I want to prevent.

This jsfiddle shows what I currently have. https://jsfiddle.net/ju637z98/

```
<span>
  <span style="width: 20px; display: inline-block;">

  </span>
  <span style="display: inline; " >
    This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.
  </span>
</span>
```

If I change the content div to

```
display: inline-block
```

the two divs end up being stacked on top of each other.

I'm trying to avoid styling the content div because the the padding div won't always be present so I'd like to avoid having two different styles to achieve what I need.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: updated the snipped above and the jsfiddle to use spans instead of divs.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Spans can't contain divs

Comment: your html structure is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would erase that first DIV and use `margin-left: 20px;` (or whatever value) on the content DIV (and make that an `inline-block`)

```html
<span>
  <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px;" >
    This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.
  </div>
</span>
```

Comment: This is what I went with and just added to code to set the margin-left to 20 or 0 depending on whether or not I needing the left-margin (instead of conditionally inserting the extra div).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the parent `flex` and use `flex-basis` on the first div to control that column width.

```css
span {
  display: flex;
}
.padding {
  flex: 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <div class="padding">
  </div>
  <div>
    This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.
  </div>
</span>
```

You could also `float` the padding div and use `overflow: auto` on the non-floating to contain the text.

```css
.padding {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 1em;
}
span div:nth-child(2) {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <div class="padding">
  </div>
  <div>
    This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.
  </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper{
  padding-left:20px;
  border:thin black solid;
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.
</div>
```

Is this the same that you want?
Hope this helps.